# curl not updating shopify api

Tags: php, api, curl, shopify

Wondering why this code doesn't update my product. I have tested in the chrome rest console and works great. However, when testing the curl in php it doesn't update. I have tested doing a simple GET request for product count with curl in php and it responded fine. Just the PUT is giving me fits. Anything stand out?

```
<?php
$baseUrl = https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/';


$variant =
array('inventory_quantity' => 20
);

$ch = curl_init($baseUrl.'variants/19175889219.json');  //note product ID in url
$data_string = json_encode(array('variant'=>$variant)); //json encode the product array
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");  //specify the PUT verb for update
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);  //add the data string for the request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //set return as string true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
); //set the header as JSON
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch); //execute and store server output
curl_close ($ch); //close the connection

echo $data_string;
echo $server_output;


?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Php doesnt error and i dont get a response back, good or bad. The output is my payload echo.

Comment: Can you share the output? I think I know the issue.

Comment: {"variant":{"inventory_quantity":20}}

Comment: Think I figured it out. After research I added...curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); Worked better.